# loading JSON data dynamically vs hardcoded in JVectormap - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jvectormap

I am using JVectormap and I'm trying to load data dynamically through AJAX.
My AJAX calls a PHP script which returns a resultstring.
Example response : {"US":"29.84","BE":"24.52","FR":"21.42","GB":"15.66"}

When I use console.log(dataset) I see the exact correct string as the example above in the console, but data is not loaded on the geo chart and I get the error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined"**

When I copy paste the value from console and add a line in my code that states
var dataset = {"US":"29.84","BE":"24.52","FR":"21.42","GB":"15.66"};
then the chart is loaded perfectly.

So when I hardcode the value all works fine, but when I use the dynamically returned dataset it doesn't work, although they are exact copies of eachother.

**My Javascript code without the hardcoded value (this one results in empty map and the above mentionned error in console)**

*Information : This function RenderChart(dataset) is called from another part which loads the AJAX data in "dataset".* So dataset contains the string with country codes and values as you can also see with console.log(dataset);

```
function RenderChart(dataset)
{
    console.log(dataset);
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill',
            backgroundColor: "#3C454D",
            series: {
                regions: [{
                    values: dataset,
                    scale: ['#25823b', '#fce853', '#e01402'],
                    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                }]
            },
            onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
                el.html(el.html()+' (Threat - '+dataset[code]+'%)');
            }
        });
}
```

**My code WITH the hardcoded value (this one results in a good chart)**

```
function RenderChart(dataset)
{
    console.log(dataset);
    dataset = {"US":"29.84","BE":"24.52","FR":"21.42","GB":"15.66","DE":"2.81"};
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill',
            backgroundColor: "#3C454D",
            series: {
                regions: [{
                    values: dataset,
                    scale: ['#25823b', '#fce853', '#e01402'],
                    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                }]
            },
            onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
                el.html(el.html()+' (Threat - '+dataset[code]+'%)');
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it myself but thought I'd add the solution here for other people perhaps having the same issue.

Although the PHP code returns a json_encode() value, it doesn't work.
You have to explicitely define **dataType: "json"** inside the AJAX request.